# Discrete Fourier Transforms in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, fft

I want to present the pulse wave using Highcharts.
With idea data, the chart is fine as
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg9zh.png)

However, when there are noises, the algorithm does not work
[image with bad points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVqSE.png)

so I decided to do with Fourier transform.

Is there any library can do the DFT? or I have to write it myself.

please tell me the library name or way to solve this question and how do you get the idea.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/scijs/fourier-transform/blob/master/benchmark.md gives a nice list to start with, or search [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=fourier+transform)

Comment: Due to my poor math and eng... although I had read the repository [fourier](https://github.com/drom/fourier) days ago， I didn't get how to use it to do 1d fft... can you just show me about how to transform the 'sin(x)' with it? thanks!

Comment: I have coded another function  to solve this problem and it works well to replace the thorns of the wave. and here it is (you need to set proper two value at the very begin)`Array.prototype.smooth = function (strength) {
    var len = this.length;
    var dis_arg, dis, dis_sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        dis_sum += Math.abs((this[i + 1] - this[i]));
        dis_arg = dis_sum / i;
        dis = Math.abs(this[i + 1] - this[i]);
        if (dis / dis_arg > strength) {
            this[i + 1] = 2 * this[i] - this[i - 1];
        }
    }
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may implement it by yourself if you want. Here is an example of how Discrete Fourier Transform function may be implemented in ES6:

```js
import ComplexNumber from '../complex-number/ComplexNumber';

const CLOSE_TO_ZERO_THRESHOLD = 1e-10;

/**
 * Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT): time to frequencies.
 *
 * Time complexity: O(N^2)
 *
 * @param {number[]} inputAmplitudes - Input signal amplitudes over time (complex
 * numbers with real parts only).
 * @param {number} zeroThreshold - Threshold that is used to convert real and imaginary numbers
 * to zero in case if they are smaller then this.
 *
 * @return {ComplexNumber[]} - Array of complex number. Each of the number represents the frequency
 * or signal. All signals together will form input signal over discrete time periods. Each signal's
 * complex number has radius (amplitude) and phase (angle) in polar form that describes the signal.
 *
 * @see https://gist.github.com/anonymous/129d477ddb1c8025c9ac
 * @see https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/
 */
export default function dft(inputAmplitudes, zeroThreshold = CLOSE_TO_ZERO_THRESHOLD) {
  const N = inputAmplitudes.length;
  const signals = [];

  // Go through every discrete frequency.
  for (let frequency = 0; frequency < N; frequency += 1) {
    // Compound signal at current frequency that will ultimately
    // take part in forming input amplitudes.
    let frequencySignal = new ComplexNumber();

    // Go through every discrete point in time.
    for (let timer = 0; timer < N; timer += 1) {
      const currentAmplitude = inputAmplitudes[timer];

      // Calculate rotation angle.
      const rotationAngle = -1 * (2 * Math.PI) * frequency * (timer / N);

      // Remember that e^ix = cos(x) + i * sin(x);
      const dataPointContribution = new ComplexNumber({
        re: Math.cos(rotationAngle),
        im: Math.sin(rotationAngle),
      }).multiply(currentAmplitude);

      // Add this data point's contribution.
      frequencySignal = frequencySignal.add(dataPointContribution);
    }

    // Close to zero? You're zero.
    if (Math.abs(frequencySignal.re) < zeroThreshold) {
      frequencySignal.re = 0;
    }

    if (Math.abs(frequencySignal.im) < zeroThreshold) {
      frequencySignal.im = 0;
    }

    // Average contribution at this frequency.
    // The 1/N factor is usually moved to the reverse transform (going from frequencies
    // back to time). This is allowed, though it would be nice to have 1/N in the forward
    // transform since it gives the actual sizes for the time spikes.
    frequencySignal = frequencySignal.divide(N);

    // Add current frequency signal to the list of compound signals.
    signals[frequency] = frequencySignal;
  }

  return signals;
}
```

This function is just directly implements the formula:

[image]

The function is pretty slow and has `O(n^2)` time complexity. If speed **does** matter to you you may go with [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) instead:

More details with descriptions here https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/tree/master/src/algorithms/math/fourier-transform

Answer (score 0):

I made a suggestion in another thread on Stack Overflow: [Fast Fourier Transform Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316538/fast-fourier-transform-javascript) .
It accepts entry of a 1D array, assumes they are equally spaced, and outputs the DFT. Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

Comment: actually I'm looking for a library which can be used like the way in matlab -- fft() thanks, I'll working on your suggestion